# how does javascript reference a variable inside a callback?

Tags: javascript

So if I have some javascript like:

```
Foo.init = function(options) {
  Bar.set_listener('some_event', function() {
    console.log(options);
  });
};
```

where I call Foo.init with some options like Foo.init({whatever: 'hi'}) and that Bar.set_listener method takes the callback and stores it, and then invokes it at some later time when 'some_event' is triggered....

will console.log print undefined or {whatever: 'hi'} ?  The answer seems to be {whatever: 'hi'} but that confuses me.  How does this callback when invoked have any idea how to reference the options variable passed in to Foo.init?

Comment: You need to read up on 'closures' in Javascript. The explanation is too long to be an answer here.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Closure_%28computer_science%29

Comment: It does log `{whatever: 'hi'}`. How, that's an implementation detail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ability of an inner function to reference state defined in an outer function is known as closures.  This is a feature present in the majority of languages that allow for lambdas, or function values.

How it's implemented is worthy of a post much longer than can really be said in a Stack Overflow answer.  But in summary the Javascript runtime will persist the values defined in an outer function so long as there is an inner function alive that references them.